# ASP.NET MVC : Find record get null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating the inventory system in ASP.NET MVC. I ran into the problem with finding the when I enter the id on the textbox relevant result need to display but I am getting error on this line

```
var std = dc.products.Where(a => a.id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get an error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
> Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

What I tried so far I attached below

Screenshot showing null:

[image]

Index.chtml

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <caption> Add Products  </caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Product Code</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Option</th>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
     <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control"
           placeholder="barcode" id="barcode" name="barcode" 
           size="25px" required>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="barcode" id="pname" name="pname" size="50px" disabled>
                @*<label id="pro_name" name="pname" id="pname"></label>*@
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control pro_price" id="pro_price" size="25px" name="pro_price"
                       placeholder="price" disabled>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control pro_price" id="qty" name="qty"
                       placeholder="qty" min="1" value="1" size="10px" required>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="total_cost" size="35px" id="total_cost" name="total_cost" disabled>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="addproduct()">
                    Add
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

`HomeController`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Getid(String Id)
{
    // Get the student from studentList sample collection for demo purpose.
    // Get the student from the database in the real application
    var std = dc.products.Where(a => a.id == Id).FirstOrDefault();

    // return new JsonResult { Data = new { std = std } };
    return Json(std, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Model class:

```
public partial class product
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string proname { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> cat_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> brand_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> qty { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> price { get; set; }
}
```

Connection String

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication4-20220414085040.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication4-20220414085040;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   
    <add name="posEntities5" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pos;User ID=sa;Password=***********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

**Sql Screen Shot**
[image]

Comment: Check your connection string.

Comment: i added the connection string above\

Comment: what is the problem with the connection string

Answer (score 0):

The exception that you mentioned is probably related to the connection string.
you can check it with Visual Studio's SQL Server Object Explorer.

Go to the **View** menu and then choose **SQL Server Object Explorer**

[image: SQL Server Object Explorer]

Then under the SQL Server tree, right-click on your database and choose properties. and select Connection String which you probably like the following connection string (Probably much longer):

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;
```

Then change `Initial Catalog` from `master` to whatever your database name is and use it as the simplest connection string inside your configuration file and see if it can connect or not.

If it connects then you have to edit your config file and connection string to fix the `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException`

Comment: screen shot i attached above i did like this now but same error

Comment: Connection string i updated can you check it

Comment: I cannot check your connection string, because I don't have access to the project. You should check it in your project and see if everything is wired up correctly.

Comment: can i have your email i will send it to u

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. Stackoverflow is for helping to answer questions and learn. It not for Freelancing.

Comment: ok....................................................................

Comment: Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'data source'. i am getting the error